# Determine the number of cubes in mod $13^5$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Determine the number of elements in $Z/13^5Z$ (respectively $Z/(11×13^2
)Z$) which are cubes, i.e.
the third power of elements of $Z/13^5Z$ (respectively $Z/(11×13^2
)Z$)

My start: $g$ is a primitive root, so we need to determine how many distinct elements we can get of the form $(g^a)^3\mod 13^5$ where $a$ ranges from $1 \ldots m = \phi(13^5)$. From here I am a bit confused as to find how many elements there are, and then how many third powers in total. We were given a hint for the last step: "if an element of $Z/13^5Z$ can be written as $x = 13^i*b$ where $b$ is coprime to 13, what can you say about $x^3 = 13^{3i}*b^3$?"

Comment: Why must a primitive root exist?  $13^5$ is not prime.

Comment: @MichaelBurr's comment is what came to my mind when I first saw this as well. Take for example, 8. The invertible elements are the ones which are odd numbers but all of them square to 1.

Comment: @MIchaelBurr For some $g'$ that is a primitive root mod 13, there either $g'$ or $g' + 13$ is a primitive root mod $13^5$. This is because 13 is an odd prime, which is where the second comment is running into a problem, right? If I should solve this problem in a different direction I am open to it.

Comment: You need to invoke the Chinese remainder Theorem and the structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$

Comment: @Jnelz is referring to Hensel's Lemma. As for $\phi(13^5)$, this is $\phi(13^5)=13^5-13^4=12\times 13^4$. See Euler's totient function for computing the values of $\phi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x=13^ib$, we can do cases with $i$.  If $i\geq 2$, then $x^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{13^5},$ which gives us $1$ cube.

If $i=0$, then we count the cubes relatively prime to $13$.  These are exactly the powers of $g^3$ and there are $\phi(13^5)/3 = 4\times 13^4$ of them.

If $i=1$, then we seek cubes of the form $13^3b^3 \pmod{13^5}$.  If $x^3 \equiv 13^3b^3 \pmod{13^5},$ then $x=13y$ for some $y$ and we have $y \equiv b^3 \pmod{13^2}.$  If $h$ is a primitive root of $13^2$, we argue as above and count $\phi(13^2)/3 = 4\times 13=52$ more cubes.

That gives $1 +4\times 13^4 +52=114,297$ cubes in all.